# Median comparisons and population size

Tags: sample, median, small-sample

Suppose I have the following data, which corresponds to the median rental price of distinct areas:

```
Area          | Median Rental Price | Nr Houses
Soho          |   $2,500            |   15
Harlem        |   $2,400            |  250
Chelsea       |   $3,500            |    2
East Village  |   $1,500            |   10
```

Basically, this means that for Soho I used 15 houses to calculate the median rental price.

If I want to compare the distinct areas to see which ones are most expensive/cheap to live is there a formula I can use to ignore an area due to having a smaller population in the data set?

Comment: [There are indeed formulas,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=confidence+median) as well as [tests,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance)  but they all require information you don't display: you must have information about the likely spread of prices around each median.  Do you have the original data?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, for each area I have the rental price of each house in the population.